# Pass original CSS value in jQuery resize and each function

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, scale, each

I have an image slider with multiple instances of absolutely positioned text overlaid on top of an image (the top position of the text is defined in an MS-SQL database and pulled in via JSON). When the screen loads (if it is less than scale = 1) & when screen resizes I'd like to use a scale function to keep the absolutely positioned text containers at a certain number of pixels (updated using a scale function) from the top of the div which wraps around the image slider. The image is 100% width, but as the screen is resized the image height will vary, so the absolutely positioned text will not remain its original position in relation to the image (the client decides the top position of the overlay text for the full screen version). Here is some example code:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <img />
        <div class="overlay_holder" style="position:absolute; top:100px;>Some text</div>
        <div class="overlay_holder" style="position:absolute; top:150px;>Some text</div>
        <div class="overlay_holder" style="position:absolute; top:180px;>Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery, the only trouble I am having is that I need to somehow pass into the function the original CSS top value of each overlay_holder div:

function doScaleTop(event, ui) {
      var scale, origin;

```
  scale = Math.min(
    ui.size.width / elWidth,
    ui.size.height / elHeight
  );

  $('.overlay_holder').each(function(index, el) {
    var top = $(this).css('top');   // This is the problem line of code  - I somehow need the original CSS top value defined in the JSON
    top = top.replace('px','');
    var newTop = top*scale;
    if (newTop != 0 && newTop != '' && newTop != null && isNaN(newTop) == false) {
      newTop = newTop.toFixed(2);
    }

    $(this).css({
      top: newTop+'px'
    });
  });
}

var starterData = {
  size: {
    width: $wrapper.width(),
    height: $wrapper.height()
  }
}

doScaleTop(null, starterData);

$(window).resize(function(event) {
  var newData = {
    size: {
      width: $wrapper.width(),
      height: $wrapper.height()
    }
  }
  doScaleTop(null,newData);
});
```

The JSON looks like this - the y value is the top position for each text overlay (each one the overlays has a class of overlay_holder) :

```
imgDef = [
{ type:'L', active:'Y', img:'GARDN.jpg', alt:'Tools', textoverlays: [ { x:0, y:45, r:0, mx:0, my:0, mr:0, text:'Only the Finest' }, { x:0, y:130, r:0, mx:0, my:0, mr:0, text:'TAKE A LOOK >' } ]
}
{ type:'L', active:'Y', img:'GARDN.jpg', alt:'Tools', textoverlays: [ { x:0, y:45, r:0, mx:0, my:0, mr:0, text:'Only the Finest' }, { x:0, y:130, r:0, mx:0, my:0, mr:0, text:'TAKE A LOOK >' } ]
}
];
```

Can anyone help? I think I may need to use a map function but I'm not 100% sure to be honest.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Try `parseFloat(el.style.top)`.

Comment: Use jQuery data() to store values on each element http://api.jquery.com/data/. Can pass whole objects to it or key/value pairs

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I tried $('.overlay_holder').data('top',$('.overlay_holder').css('top');  and then in the scale function I used $.each($.data(this), function(i, e) { var top = e;  });   but I got the same result